# Riemann integrable function on every subinterval

Tags: riemann-integration

Suppose $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded and Riemann integrable function on [c,b] for every c in (a,b). Prove that f is Riemann integrable on all [a,b].

I am trying to use the Darboux criterion to solve this problem. For a given epsilon, I choose a partition of the interval [c,b] and try to relate it to a partition of the interval [a,b]. The problem is that the sup and inf of f may change when we add [a,c] to our partition. Also, by the same token, I cannot use a limit argument to send c to a. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "fastest" (though not elementary) way is to deduce that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: I do not want to use measure theory. @AndrewZhang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $[a,b]$  such that $$U_{[a,b]}(\mathcal{P},f)-L_{[a,b]}(\mathcal{P},f)<\varepsilon$$ where $U$ and $L$ denote the upper and the lower Riemann sums.

Let $M=\sup |f(x)|.$ For fixed $\varepsilon >0$ let
$c$ be chosen so that $c\le a+{\varepsilon\over 4M}.$
By assumptions there is a partition $\mathcal{P}_0$ of $[c,b]$ such that $$U_{[c,b]}(\mathcal{P}_0,f)-L_{[c,b]}(\mathcal{P}_0,f)<{\varepsilon\over 2}$$
Then for $\mathcal{P}=\{a\}\cup \mathcal{P}_0$ we have
$$U_{[a,b]}(\mathcal{P},f)-L_{[a,b]}(\mathcal{P},f)\\
\le {\varepsilon\over 2}+U_{[c,b]}(\mathcal{P}_0,f)-L_{[c,b]}(\mathcal{P}_0,f)<\varepsilon $$

Comment: Technically that's Darboux integrable. It turns out to be equivalent to Riemann integrable, but I personally prefer Darboux as it is often easier to argue about.